# What is "repl-writer-worker" in mongo logs

Tags: mongodb

Someone or something is dropping my collections on prod, when I download the logs I found this:

```
[repl-writer-worker-4192] CMD: drop meteor.products
```

before that I don't see any ACCESS log with that IP or that name.
Is it a mongo cron job? Does someone have access to my database? is it an injection attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This log message seems taken from SECONDARY member , but it replicate the drop command that is sent to the PRIMARY :

```
 REPL [repl writer worker-4192] CMD: drop meteor.products
```

repl writer is automatic process that replicate and apply oplog commands to SECONDARY database.
You will need to review logs from mongoses and PRIMARY to identify who sent this command.

In the PRIMARY search for line like:

```
 COMMAND  [conn46] CMD: drop meteor.products
```

where later searching by the connectionId #46  you can identify the connection client IP:

```
NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50642 #46
```

and client details like:

```
 NETWORK  [conn46] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:50642 conn46: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.2.14" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "22.04" } }
```

Comment: Couldn't have answered it better :) nailed it!